# Is it normal for an LDAP extract to have multiple OUs for a single record?

Tags: directory, ldap, ldap-query

I have an LDAP extract with records that are in the format: CN=, OU=, OU=, OU=, and so on with up to 8 OUs! Some also have two CNs...

Comment: This question is really asking for an opinion.

Comment: Does this have to do with programming? From the tag wiki: `Non-programming networking questions are off topic and should be asked on Network Engineering, Super User or Server Fault instead.`

Comment: @jdv Not really, it asking for normal practice, which is practice, not opinion.

Comment: Is it "normal"? Maybe, depending on how you inherited the tree or subtree you are working on. Ok, let's paraphrase the question: is is common practice? I suppose yes, but with caveats. This hies too close to opinion for my tastes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, no problem, my DIT has

```
dc=com,dc=mydomain,ou=Users,ou=Customers,ou=clientnameXXX,cn=userNameYYY
```

for example, reading it backwards.

But I would add that any DIT that goes 8 deep is probably over-organised. All the books warn against it using it to mirror your organisational structure, for example.